# I have HTTP error 404 when redirecting in my MVC3 app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

In my application I have a route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "ILRoute",
        url: "{*Path}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Page", action = "index", Path = "" });
```

And in my controller I get the path and find what page was called and return the view that I want with page data.

It works fine when I am running on VS 2010 but when I upload to the server I get the error 404 when calling some pages. For example: I have menu that link attr set to 'channels'. In VS 2010 it works fine and when the menu is clicked the channel page appears but on the server a 404 error appears. I changed the URL in my browser manually to this:

> myserverIP/websiteNAme/Home

and in this state when I click on the "channel" menu the page appears! But in the last state the browser says: File or directory not found, browser try to access this URL:

> MyServerIP/channel

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/04/22/test-you-asp-net-mvc-or-webforms-application-on-iis-7-in-30-seconds.aspx

Comment: @rick-anderson-at-microsoft-com its work fine when starting on visual studio but when publishing on server not working

Comment: my website loading this url=> "/websiteName"
but i want load this url => "/websiteName/Home" 
in vs when start debugging load correct url but on server when use browse *80(http) button its load this url "/websiteName"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found solution to solve problem 
i use **"/"** and **domain name** and **menu link** like this 
**"/domainName/MenuLink** 
so when user click on the menu the url going correctly 
tnx every body